# Android O - Change Notification Channel Name from Manifest

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

How can I change Notification Channel name from manifest.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="My Selected Channel ID" />
```

I see above code from somewhere to change ID.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_name"
        android:value="My Selected Channel ID" />
```

I tried above code for changing name, but I could not see any changes.

Comment: Once a channel is created it cannot be changed

Comment: This was not the question here. The default channel name is Miscallenous. There must be a way to override its name through Manifest